# ExpressionVisitor soft delete

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-expressions, soft-delete, expressionvisitor

We're having some issues implementing soft delete functionality with entity framework. The idea is to use a repository which is aware of the EF context. On the level of the repository we implemented a plugin system, these plugins get executed whenever an action is done on the repository. For example when we call `Repository.GetQuery<Relation>()` the plugins get executed. One of the plugins is a `LogicalDeletePlugin`, this plugin should add a `Where(x => x.IsDeleted)` statement to each table which is in the select. The idea was to implement this `IsDeleted` plugin using an `ExpressionVisitor` which visits the linq expression and finds all the "table" select statements and add the `IsDeleted` condition.

To clarify the question/problem I'll explain the issue using some code examples.

```
void Main()
{
var options = new ReadonlyRepositoryOptions() { ConnectionStringDelegate = () => Connection.ConnectionString };
using (var context = new ReadonlyObjectContextRepository<PFishEntities>(options))
{
var query = context.GetQuery<Relation>()
.Select(x => new {
Test = x.Bonus,
TestWorks = x.Bonus.Where(y => y.bonID == 100)
});

query.InterceptWith(new TestVisitor()).ToList();
}
}

public class TestVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
private ParameterExpression Parameter { get; set; }

protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node) {
"VisitBinary".Dump();
Expression left = this.Visit(node.Left);
Expression right = this.Visit(node.Right);

var newParams = new[] { Parameter };
var condition = (LambdaExpression)new LogicalDeletePlugin().QueryConditionals.First().Conditional;
var paramMap = condition.Parameters.Select((original, i) => new { original, replacement = newParams[i] }).ToDictionary(p => p.original, p => p.replacement);

var fixedBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(paramMap, condition.Body);
return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.AndAlso, node, fixedBody, node.IsLiftedToNull, node.Method);
    }

protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression expr)
{
Parameter = expr;
return base.VisitParameter(expr);
}
}
void Main()
{
    var options = new ReadonlyRepositoryOptions() { ConnectionStringDelegate = () => Connection.ConnectionString };
    using (var context = new ReadonlyObjectContextRepository<PFishEntities>(options))
    {
        var query = context.GetQuery<Relation>()
        .Select(x => new {
            Test = x.Bonus,
            TestWorks = x.Bonus.Where(y => y.bonID == 100)
        });

        query.InterceptWith(new TestVisitor()).ToList();
    }
}

public class TestVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    private ParameterExpression Parameter { get; set; }

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node) {
        "VisitBinary".Dump();
        Expression left = this.Visit(node.Left);
        Expression right = this.Visit(node.Right);

        var newParams = new[] { Parameter };
        var condition = (LambdaExpression)new LogicalDeletePlugin().QueryConditionals.First().Conditional;
        var paramMap = condition.Parameters.Select((original, i) => new { original, replacement = newParams[i] }).ToDictionary(p => p.original, p => p.replacement);
        var fixedBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(paramMap, condition.Body);
        return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.AndAlso, node, fixedBody, node.IsLiftedToNull, node.Method);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression expr)
    {
        Parameter = expr;
        return base.VisitParameter(expr);
    }
}
```

The above c# code will result in the following SQL code :

```
SELECT 
[UnionAll1].[relID] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C3], 
[UnionAll1].[bonID] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll1].[bonCUSTOMERID] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll1].[bonRELATIONARTICLEBONUSID] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll1].[bonINVOICEID] AS [C7], 
[UnionAll1].[bonSALEROWID] AS [C8], 
[UnionAll1].[bonVALUE] AS [C9], 
[UnionAll1].[bonPERCENTAGE] AS [C10], 
[UnionAll1].[bonMANUAL] AS [C11], 
[UnionAll1].[bonPAID] AS [C12], 
[UnionAll1].[IsDeleted] AS [C13], 
[UnionAll1].[InternalReference] AS [C14], 
[UnionAll1].[ConcurrencyToken] AS [C15], 
[UnionAll1].[Created] AS [C16], 
[UnionAll1].[CreatedBy] AS [C17], 
[UnionAll1].[Updated] AS [C18], 
[UnionAll1].[UpdatedBy] AS [C19], 
[UnionAll1].[DisplayMember] AS [C20], 
[UnionAll1].[ValueMember] AS [C21], 
[UnionAll1].[SearchField] AS [C22], 
[UnionAll1].[CreateDate] AS [C23], 
[UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C24], 
[UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C25], 
[UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C26], 
[UnionAll1].[C6] AS [C27], 
[UnionAll1].[C7] AS [C28], 
[UnionAll1].[C8] AS [C29], 
[UnionAll1].[C9] AS [C30], 
[UnionAll1].[C10] AS [C31], 
[UnionAll1].[C11] AS [C32], 
[UnionAll1].[C12] AS [C33], 
[UnionAll1].[C13] AS [C34], 
[UnionAll1].[C14] AS [C35], 
[UnionAll1].[C15] AS [C36], 
[UnionAll1].[C16] AS [C37], 
[UnionAll1].[C17] AS [C38], 
[UnionAll1].[C18] AS [C39], 
[UnionAll1].[C19] AS [C40], 
[UnionAll1].[C20] AS [C41], 
[UnionAll1].[C21] AS [C42], 
[UnionAll1].[C22] AS [C43]
FROM  (SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[bonID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[relID] AS [relID], 
    1 AS [C2], 
    [Extent2].[bonID] AS [bonID], 
    [Extent2].[bonCUSTOMERID] AS [bonCUSTOMERID], 
    [Extent2].[bonRELATIONARTICLEBONUSID] AS [bonRELATIONARTICLEBONUSID], 
    [Extent2].[bonINVOICEID] AS [bonINVOICEID], 
    [Extent2].[bonSALEROWID] AS [bonSALEROWID], 
    [Extent2].[bonVALUE] AS [bonVALUE], 
    [Extent2].[bonPERCENTAGE] AS [bonPERCENTAGE], 
    [Extent2].[bonMANUAL] AS [bonMANUAL], 
    [Extent2].[bonPAID] AS [bonPAID], 
    [Extent2].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
    [Extent2].[InternalReference] AS [InternalReference], 
    [Extent2].[ConcurrencyToken] AS [ConcurrencyToken], 
    [Extent2].[Created] AS [Created], 
    [Extent2].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Extent2].[Updated] AS [Updated], 
    [Extent2].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy], 
    [Extent2].[DisplayMember] AS [DisplayMember], 
    [Extent2].[ValueMember] AS [ValueMember], 
    [Extent2].[SearchField] AS [SearchField], 
    [Extent2].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C3], 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C4], 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C5], 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C6], 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C7], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(20,4)) AS [C8], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(20,4)) AS [C9], 
    CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C10], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(20,4)) AS [C11], 
    CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C12], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C13], 
    CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C14], 
    CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) AS [C15], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C16], 
    CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) AS [C17], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C18], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C19], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C20], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C21], 
    CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C22]
    FROM  [dbo].[Relation] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Bonus] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[relID] = [Extent2].[bonCUSTOMERID]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    2 AS [C1], 
    [Extent3].[relID] AS [relID], 
    2 AS [C2], 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C3], 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C4], 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C5], 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C6], 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C7], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(20,4)) AS [C8], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(20,4)) AS [C9], 
    CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C10], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(20,4)) AS [C11], 
    CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C12], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C13], 
    CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C14], 
    CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) AS [C15], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C16], 
    CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) AS [C17], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C18], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C19], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C20], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C21], 
    CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C22], 
    [Extent4].[bonID] AS [bonID], 
    [Extent4].[bonCUSTOMERID] AS [bonCUSTOMERID], 
    [Extent4].[bonRELATIONARTICLEBONUSID] AS [bonRELATIONARTICLEBONUSID], 
    [Extent4].[bonINVOICEID] AS [bonINVOICEID], 
    [Extent4].[bonSALEROWID] AS [bonSALEROWID], 
    [Extent4].[bonVALUE] AS [bonVALUE], 
    [Extent4].[bonPERCENTAGE] AS [bonPERCENTAGE], 
    [Extent4].[bonMANUAL] AS [bonMANUAL], 
    [Extent4].[bonPAID] AS [bonPAID], 
    [Extent4].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
    [Extent4].[InternalReference] AS [InternalReference], 
    [Extent4].[ConcurrencyToken] AS [ConcurrencyToken], 
    [Extent4].[Created] AS [Created], 
    [Extent4].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Extent4].[Updated] AS [Updated], 
    [Extent4].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy], 
    [Extent4].[DisplayMember] AS [DisplayMember], 
    [Extent4].[ValueMember] AS [ValueMember], 
    [Extent4].[SearchField] AS [SearchField], 
    [Extent4].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate]
    FROM  [dbo].[Relation] AS [Extent3]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Bonus] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent3].[relID] = [Extent4].[bonCUSTOMERID]) AND (100 = [Extent4].[bonID]) AND ([Extent4].[IsDeleted] <> cast(1 as bit))) AS [UnionAll1]
ORDER BY [UnionAll1].[relID] ASC, [UnionAll1].[C1] ASC
```

As you can see in the resulting SQL query the `IsDeleted` statements gets added to the `TestWorks = x.Bonus.Where(y => !y.IsDeleted)` "select" code. That's what the `TestVisitor` is currently doing. But the question is now how we can also implement this on the other selects, the `x => !x.IsDeleted` doesn't get added on the `Test = x.Bonus` part.

Is the ExpressionVisitor the correct approach to get this done or should I go with another solution? All help is appreciated! If the explanation wasn't clear enough just let me know and I'll try to give some additional info!

Edit:

```
protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var test = typeof(bool);
        if (node.Type != test && node.Type != typeof(string))
        {
            var type = typeof(ArticleVat);
            var condition = (LambdaExpression)Condition;
            var newParams = new[] { Expression.Parameter(type, "x") };
            var paramMap = condition.Parameters.Select((original, i) => new { original, replacement = newParams[i] }).ToDictionary(p => p.original, p => p.replacement);
            var fixedBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(paramMap, condition.Body);
            condition = Expression.Lambda(fixedBody, newParams);
            var whereM = whereMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new [] { type });
            var expr = Expression.Property(node.Expression, "ArticleVat");
            var whereExpr = Expression.Call(whereM, expr, condition);
//          whereExpr.Dump();
node.Dump();
//          return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(whereExpr, node.Expression.Type.GetMember(node.Member.Name).Single());
//           return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
//                whereExpr,
//                node.Expression.Type.GetMember(node.Member.Name).Single());
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
```

The above is what I've added to the ExpressionVisitor. Now when I uncomment the return Expression.MamkeMemberaccess code an exception is thrown because it doesn't expect a MemberExpression or something.

Following is the solution I came up with :

```
/// <summary>
/// This visitor will append a .Where(QueryCondition) clause for a given Condition to each Navigation property
/// </summary>
public class InjectConditionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private QueryConditional QueryCondition { get; set; }

    public InjectConditionVisitor(QueryConditional condition)
    {
        QueryCondition = condition;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression ex)
    {
        // Only change generic types = Navigation Properties
        // else just execute the normal code.
        return !ex.Type.IsGenericType ? base.VisitMember(ex) : CreateWhereExpression(QueryCondition, ex) ?? base.VisitMember(ex);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create the where expression with the adapted QueryConditional
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="condition">The condition to use</param>
    /// <param name="ex">The MemberExpression we're visiting</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Expression CreateWhereExpression(QueryConditional condition, Expression ex)
    {
        var type = ex.Type.GetGenericArguments().First();
        var test = CreateExpression(condition, type);
        if (test == null)
            return null;
        var listType = typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        return Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Where", new Type[] { type }, (Expression)ex, test), listType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adapt a QueryConditional to the member we're currently visiting.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="condition">The condition to adapt</param>
    /// <param name="type">The type of the current member (=Navigation property)</param>
    /// <returns>The adapted QueryConditional</returns>
    private LambdaExpression CreateExpression(QueryConditional condition, Type type)
    {
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression)condition.Conditional;
        var conditionType = condition.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
        // Only continue when the condition is applicable to the Type of the member
        if (conditionType == null)
            return null;
        if (!conditionType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
            return null;

        var newParams = new[] { Expression.Parameter(type, "bo") };
        var paramMap = lambda.Parameters.Select((original, i) => new { original, replacement = newParams[i] }).ToDictionary(p => p.original, p => p.replacement);
        var fixedBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(paramMap, lambda.Body);
        lambda = Expression.Lambda(fixedBody, newParams);

        return lambda;
    }
}
```

QueryConditional is a class which holds an Expression of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

The InjectconditionVisitor can be used in combination with InterceptWith (QueryInterceptor NuGet package) like `query.InterceptWith(new InjectConditionVisitor(new QueryConditional(x => x.Deleted == true))`.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. You say `QueryConditional` is a class where, I'm assuming, the `Conditional` property is an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. But where does `T` come from? When you say `QueryConditional(x => x.Deleted == true))` where is `x`'s type defined? It seems like `T` would have to be a specific base class or interface or `QueryConditional` would have to be a generic class `QueryConditional<T>`. Also what is `ParameterRebinder`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `ExpressionVisitor` is the correct approach.

You need to transform `x.Bonus` into `x.Bonus.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)`. I suggest you do the same thing for `x.Bonus.Where(y => y.bonID == 100)`. Transform it into `x.Bonus.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).Where(y => y.bonID == 100)`

This means that you need to convert any Expression of type `IQueryable<Bonus>` to another expression of type `IQueryable<Bonus>`, but with the where-clause appended.

You probably need to override the very general `ExpressionVisitor.Visit` method to visit *all* expressions, not just binary ones.

You are very likely to run into special cases here that you haven't thought about yet. This is going to be difficult, but fun :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't had a lot of time to continue working on this problem. The last thing I ran against was that when you look at the linq code is that the x.Bonus.Where(x => X...) is of a different type as the x.Bonus code. Been trying to convert the x.Bonus to a x.Bonus.Where but without any luck. Do you perhaps have an idea how this can be done ?

Comment: I think what you want is `(x.Bonus.IsDeleted ? null : x.Bonus)`. This might be slow on the SQL side because EF might translate this into an inefficient form.

Answer (score -1):

Victory! Today I've created an ExpressionVisitor which appends IsDeleted where clause to each select, even in navigation properties!

Comment: I'm trying to solve this exact same problem. Can you update your answer to include the final code you came up with?

Comment: Hi user1725275, I tried following your sample code, but am not getting the same result. I've posted a new question with my code and more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532393/use-expressionvisitor-to-exclude-soft-deleted-records-in-joins). Would you please take a look?